# External-DNS with annotation filter on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 external-dns servers with annotations filters.

internal dns for private zone:

```
--annotation-filter=alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme in (internal)
```

external dns for public zone:

```
--annotation-filter=alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme in (internet-facing)
```

This allows me to setup a split horizon dns.

The above annotation works great for Ingress Controllers. However I also have Services and Services use a different type of annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
```

External DNS only supports one annotation filter though. this means the solution would be to create more external-dns instances with another annotation filter, but that seems inconvenient.

Anyone have a better solution?